# Updating iPhone 3G game for iPhone 4/5/6/6+?

Tags: iphone

I have recently revived an older iPhone project (game) that was developed in OpenGL for iPhone 3G (480/320 - landscape). I have run into a problem however. The app has black space on the top and bottom of the app (left and right sides in landscape), screenshot:

[image]

I'm under the understanding that this can be resolved by splash images, for iPhone 6, for example, simply providing a "Default-375w-667h@2x.png" file in the project is apparently enough to fully upgrade an iOS app for iPhone 6 for a lot of people. This isn't the case with me. In landscape the app comes out looking like this:

[image]

So rather than the app fitting the screen, it merely shrinks it down and pushes it to the top of the screen and the blank space moves from the left/right sides to a huge left side (bottom in portrait).

Here's how I set things up, if it helps.

The OpenGL code that I'm using for the projection:

```
CGRect rect = [glView bounds];
screen_width = rect.size.width;
screen_height = rect.size.height;
glOrthof(0, screen_width, 0, screen_height, -1, 1);
```

Rect.size.width returns 667 pixels for width when in landscape mode which is correct on iPhone 6, and rect.size.height returns 375 which is also correct. As the iPhone 3Gs pixel dimensions were 480/320 in landscape, the game still works fine and runs fine if I tell OpenGL to render to the old resolution, ASIDE from the black space on the edges, but I would really like to get rid of them if possible. Must be something simple I'm missing here. I've been up til midnight everyday after work this week trying to figure this one out.

---

Edit, full GL init code:

```
- (void) initGL {

    CGRect rect = [glView bounds]; // glView is MyEAGLView
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    screen_width = rect.size.width;
    screen_height = rect.size.height;
    glOrthof(0, screen_width, 0, screen_height, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

   // GL states
   // Load textures
}
```

Comment: The splash image will only be displayed during the start of the app.

Comment: Can you show the code that happens earlier?

Comment: @neuhaus I was under the impression that the splash image directly effects the layout during the entire execution of the app? See the first response in this page here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8300945 - so basically the launch image is all that's needed to "upgrade" to the new dimensions, unless I'm wrong?

Comment: upvoted so you are closer to have the reputation required for inline screenshots...

Comment: Have you actually named the file `Default-375w-667h@2x.png` because this is incorrect

Comment: When the glView is initialized, do you use the [[UiScreen main] bounds] ?

Comment: @Popeye Yes, and it does pull it up as expected. When I was testing with an iPhone 5, I uploaded the "Default-568h@2x.png" to the project which it correctly pulled up. However the iPhone 6 would also use this splash image and for whatever reason, renaming the iPhone 6 splash image from "Default-667@2x.png" to "Default-375w-667@2x.png" resolved this for me, so they pull up the proper images now on both devices.

Comment: @neuhaus No I'm using [glView bounds] when initializing glView, if I understand your questions correctly. One sec I will pull up my full GL code..